# Why does Brave not show the modal popup on https://bibliotheek.be

Tags: modal-dialog, popup, brave

The site https://bibliotheek.be shows a modal popup where one can accept or reject cookies. Brave doesn't show the popup, thereby rendering the site inaccessible. I searched my settings, even tried a full reset of my Brave settings, without success.

TIA for any suggestion to fix this so that above site would be accessible fom Brave.

(By the way: This problem occurs on PC and on mobile)

Answer (score 0):

The error was reported on the Brave Community forum and a fix would be rolled out in 24 hours.
So this question can be considered answered / solved.